# Create structure with field names from an array

Tags: matlab, structure, matlab-struct

Below I have a snippet of code that I am using to create a structure with field names that are defined in the array 'field_names'. This seems like a very clunky way of creating the structure.

Is there a better way that I can do this in one line? Perhaps there is some syntax trick to help me avoid the for loop?

```
%array of names to create field names from
field_names = ['num1', 'num2', 'num3', 'etc'];
data = struct()
for i = 1:length(field_names)
    data.field_names(i) = rand() %some random value, doesn't matter for now
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all, the way you've written it won't work since `field_names` should be a `cell` array, and `struct` dynamic field referencing requires parentheses:

```
data.(field_names{i}) = rand();
```

You can use `cell2struct` to construct the `struct` using those fieldnames and the desired values.

```
field_names = {'num1', 'num2', 'num3'};
values = num2cell(rand(size(field_names)));

S = cell2struct(values(:), field_names(:))

%    num1: 0.2277
%    num2: 0.4357
%    num3: 0.3111
```

You can also create all of the field and values when calling `struct` directly:

```
S = struct('num1', rand(), 'num2', rand(), 'num3', rand());
```